# Swift 4: New Viewcontroller when tapped on a cell with separate class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableview which has its own class in order to be reusable. My problem is that now I want to add:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath:IndexPath) {

tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "eventView") as! eventView 
vc.event = self.eventsToLoad[indexPath.row]
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion:nil)

}
```

But as the tableview has its own class I cannot self will not have present method. I also do not want to use segue or navigationcontroller or anything, in order to be able to use this tableview anywhere.

Comment: You need to provide some contact. Where is this code that you posted? What is `self` here?

Comment: It is in the tableview's own class, which inherits from UITableViewDelegate, and UITableViewDataSource. The above code is in didselectrowforindexpath

Answer (score 1):

If you are making the tableView to be its own delegate, then you have to add your own custom delegate to inform the presenter (in your case the viewcontroller) about the didSelectRowAt event.

Like:

```
protocol CustomTableViewDelegate: class {
    func customTableView(_ tableView: CustomTableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
}

class CustomTableView: UITableView, UITableViewDelegate {
    weak var customDelegate: CustomTableViewDelegate?
    //... other properties and UITableViewDelegate implementation
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        customDelegate?.customTableView(self, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
    }
}

class SomeViewController: CustomTableViewDelegate {
    func customTableView(_ tableView: CustomTableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "eventView") as! eventView 
        vc.event = self.eventsToLoad[indexPath.row]
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion:nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a way to go, but in `SomeViewController` you also have to add customTable (or any instance of CustomTableView).delegate = self, and it works beautifully!